# YII 2 не удается подключиться к бд при миграции

Tags: yii2, docker, pgsql

Зашел в контейнер и при вводе команды

> php yii migrate

получаю следующую ошибку

```
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.28)

Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?'

in /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:635

Stack trace:
#0 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(1015): yii\db\Connection->open()
#1 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(1002): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()
#2 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(462): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()
#3 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(894): yii\db\Schema->quoteValue('migration')
#4 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/pgsql/Schema.php(464): yii\db\Connection->quoteValue('migration')
#5 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/pgsql/Schema.php(192): yii\db\pgsql\Schema->findColumns(Object(yii\db\TableSchema))
#6 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(754): yii\db\pgsql\Schema->loadTableSchema('migration')
#7 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(193): yii\db\Schema->getTableMetadata('{{%migration}}', 'schema', true)
#8 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(211): yii\db\Schema->getTableSchema('{{%migration}}', true)
#9 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(874): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->getMigrationHistory(NULL)
#10 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(167): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->getNewMigrations()
#11 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp(0)
#12 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#14 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#15 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\console\Controller-runAction('', Array)
#16 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate', Array)
#17 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate', Array)
#18 /application/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#19 /application/yii(20): yii\base\Application->run()
#20 {main}
```

Собственно сам config/db.php:

```
    <?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=admin_panel',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
```

Также пробовал указать адрес хоста как

> localhost

собственно сам docker-compose

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    postgres:
      image: postgres:11.1-alpine
      container_name: admin-panel-postgres
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - ./basic/web/:/application
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=root
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
        - POSTGRES_DB=admin_panel
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: admin-panel-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - ./basic/:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "80:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: admin-panel-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - ./basic/:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Comment: имя сервиса в композе и есть хост `postgres`

Comment: db: container_name: Получается тут будет admin-panel-postgres ?

Answer (score 0):

Да, собственно, как заметил [Blacknife](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198308/blacknife)
в качестве хоста необходимо указывать имя сервиса БД из docker-compose